# Parfor issues with population generation

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, genetic-algorithm

I'm running a genetic algorithm and i'm trying to parallelize the population generation.
My actual code:

```
Q = [];
parfor i=1:halfPop
    pa = P(select(f),:);
    pb = P(select(f),:);
    ...
    Q = [Q; pa; pb];
end
```

Matlab gives me the error **The temporary variable Q in a parfor is uninitialized.**

So i rewrote it like this:

```
Q = [];
parfor i=1:halfPop
    pa = P(select(f),:);
    pb = P(select(f),:);
    Q(i,:) pa;
    Q(i+halfPop,:) pb;
end
```

But now i get error **The variable Q in a parfor cannot be classified.**. In the editor MATLAB tells me i cannot index in two differnt ways the same matrix inside a parfor.

What could i do?

Comment: Why do you have this inside a `parfor` loop? Is `select` a function that takes a lot of time? If not, a `for`-loop may actually be faster.

Comment: Well, i simplified the code for asking the question, in truth there are a couple other time consuming things going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parfor` tries to split `Q` into as many slices as there are iterations, so each iteration gets one slice of `Q`. In your case, each iteration should get two slices, which `parfor` cannot handle (yet).

To fix this, you can define two variables, `Qa` and `Qb`, which you can combine after the end of the `parfor` loop.

```
[Qa,Qb] = deal(zeros(halfPop,size(P,2)));
parfor i=1:halfPop
    pa = P(select(f),:);
    pb = P(select(f),:);
    Qa(i,:) = pa;
    Qb(i,:) = pb;
end 

Q = zeros(2*halfPop,size(P,2));
Q(1:2:end,:) = Qa;
Q(2:2:end,:) = Qb;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution i came up indipendently. It's not the fastest but it works.

Answer (score 1):

The " concatenation reduction" you're attempting should work if you make the concatenation with a single operand like so

```
tmp = [pa; pb];
Q = [Q; tmp];
```

Answer (score 0):

Many different option depending on whther pa and pb are consistently the same size. Matlab wants to make sure there is no risk of data "overwrite" (for lack of a better term), and it is unable to ascertain that in this case. Essentially, you can only write to the matrix once per iteration, and has be done within what it believes are "good practices".

My solution:

```
Q = zeros(halfPop,size([pa pb]);
parfor i=1:halfPop
    pa = P(select(f),:);
    pb = P(select(f),:);
    Q(i,:)= [pa pb];
end
```

Comment: @Enoon sure, but you know where everything else, you can then reorganize Q to your hearts content. Your question organizes Q in two different ways, so I wasn't sure how you wanted Q to be set up.